# rounding of digits

Tags: r

I'm having troubles with

```
set.seed(1)
sum(abs(rnorm(100)))
set.seed(1)
cumsum(abs(rnorm(100)))
```

Why does the value of the sum differ from the last value of the cumulative sum with the cumulative sum preserving the all decimal digits and sum rounding 1 digit off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of the way R prints atomic vectors.

With the default digits option set to 7 as you likely have, any value between -1 and 1 will print with seven decimal places.  Because of the way R prints atomic vectors, all other values in the vector will also have seven decimal places. Furthermore, a value of `.6264538` with digits option set to 7 must print with eight digits (`0.6264538`) because it must have a leading zero.  There are two of these values in your `rnorm()` vector.

If you look at `cumsum(abs(rnorm(100)))[100]` alone and you can see the difference (actually it becomes the same as printed value as  `sum(abs(rnorm(100)))`, although not exactly the same value).

```
sum(abs(rnorm(100)))
# [1] 71.67207
cumsum(abs(rnorm(100)))[100]
# [1] 71.67207
```

Notice that both of these values have seven digits.  Probably the most basic example of this I can think of is as follows

```
0.123456789
#[1] 0.1234568
1.123456789
#[1] 1.123457
11.123456789
# [1] 11.12346
## and so on ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Also note that this really really is about how values are printed i.e. presented. This does not change the values themselves, e.g. ...

```
set.seed(1)
d1 <- sum(abs(rnorm(100)))

set.seed(1)
d2 <- cumsum(abs(rnorm(100)))

(d1 == d2)[100]
## [1] TRUE
```